# How to set WORDPRESS_DB_HOST in docker-compose

Tags: wordpress, docker

I would like to know how to set WORDPRESS_DB_HOST in docker-compose file.

```html
wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    environment:
        WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: example
        WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: 192.168.99.100:3307

wordpress_db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
        - 3307:3306
    volumes:
        - /doc/wordpress_db:/var/lib/mysql
```

Here, "192.168.99.100" is my IP's docker machine. I would like to replace it by a dynamic value.

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about version 1 of docker-compose, but I would do it like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=example
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=wp_db
    links:
      - wordpress_db:wp_db

  wordpress_db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - /doc/wordpress_db:/var/lib/mysql
```

The thing to note is the `links` part. You can link the container to a container in another service. This allows you to reference the IP of the database with the alias `wp_db`.